# How to keep the empty element in a list using list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
ls=['ISSN1','94500','2424922X','','21693536','01464116','16879724','22042326','07419341','09272852','00015903','0324721X','']
ls = [i.zfill(8) for i in ls if i != ""]
ls

Output:
['000ISSN1',
 '00094500',
 '2424922X',
 '21693536',
 '01464116',
 '16879724',
 '22042326',
 '07419341',
 '09272852',
 '00015903',
 '0324721X']
```

However, this removed the empty element. I tried several other ways to keep the empty element:

method 1:

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
    if ls[i]!="":
        ls[i]=str(ls[i]).zfill(8)
    else:
        pass
    
ls
```

method 2:

```
def changes(ls):
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        if ls[i]!="":
            ls[i]=str(ls[i]).zfill(8)
        else:
            pass
    return ls

ls=changes(ls)
ls
```

Both methods return me with the desired output:

```
['000ISSN1',
 '00094500',
 '2424922X',
 '',
 '21693536',
 '01464116',
 '16879724',
 '22042326',
 '07419341',
 '09272852',
 '00015903',
 '0324721X',
 '']
```

I'm still wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result with list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression (`a if condition else b`) within the comprehension:

```
ls = [i.zfill(8) if i else i for i in ls]
```

Note that this shortens `if i != ""` to `if i` as only the empty string is false in a boolean context.

For your particular case, you could also use some trickery (using the fact that `True == 1, False == 0`) to keep it even shorter:

```
ls = [i.zfill(8*bool(i)) for i in ls]
```

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
ls = ['ISSN1', '94500', '2424922X', '', '21693536', '01464116', '16879724', '22042326', '07419341', '09272852',
      '00015903', '0324721X', '']
ls = [i.zfill(8) if i else i for i in ls]
print(ls)
```

output

```
['000ISSN1', '00094500', '2424922X', '', '21693536', '01464116', '16879724', '22042326', '07419341', '09272852', '00015903', '0324721X', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a 'else' in your code.

```
ls=['ISSN1','94500','2424922X','','21693536','01464116','16879724','22042326','07419341','09272852','00015903','0324721X','']
ls = [i.zfill(8) if i != "" else '' for i in ls]
ls
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @ costaparas This is not a text but the output, as mentioned